# PowerPoint VBA - Slide Show - Win11 not updating Slide Content

Tags: vba, microsoft-powerpoint

I  have a PPT slide deck (2 slides) saved as a PPTM file that are used as a countdown timer where the time remaining is controlled by VBA on slide 2.

It used to work properly when I was on Windows 10 running MS Access 365/2019.

Now that I have moved to Windows 11 with MS 365 Access. The code runs if I go to the Run Macros on the developer tab and select the sub. If I go into Slideshow, the countdown function only plays the audio generated by *SpeechLib.SpVoice* but does not update the screen content.

```
Option Explicit

Const TimerAudioFolder As String = "\\bc.baruch.cuny.edu\shares\ConflictExam\Timer_Audio\"
Const TimerSlideNumber As Integer = 2

Public Sub BAR01_Countdown()

Dim CountTimeEnd As Date
Dim myHours As Integer
Dim myMinutes As Integer
Dim mySeconds As Integer
Dim dispH As Integer
Dim dispM As Integer
Dim dispS As Integer
Dim dispTime As String
Dim secondsRemain As Integer
Dim sTalk As SpeechLib.SpVoice
Set sTalk = New SpeechLib.SpVoice
Dim bGave_90M_Warning As Boolean
    bGave_90M_Warning = False
Dim bGave_60M_Warning As Boolean
    bGave_60M_Warning = False
Dim bGave_30M_Warning As Boolean
    bGave_30M_Warning = False
Dim bGave_15M_Warning As Boolean
    bGave_15M_Warning = False
Dim bGave_10M_Warning As Boolean
    bGave_10M_Warning = False
Dim bGave_05M_Warning As Boolean
    bGave_05M_Warning = False
Dim bGave_01M_Warning As Boolean
    bGave_01M_Warning = False
Dim bGave_00M_Warning As Boolean
    bGave_00M_Warning = False
Dim countTimeStart As Date
Dim timePassed As Integer
Dim timePassedH As Integer
Dim timePassedM As Integer
Dim timePassedS As Integer

    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("Rect_CO_Header").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(9, 60, 113)
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("Rect_CO_Header").Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(254, 136, 7)
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("Rect_CO_Info").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("Rect_CO_Info").Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(9, 60, 113)
    DoEvents
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "-- WAIT --"
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("SubTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Please Wait. " & Now
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("CurrentTimeHeading").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "The Current Time Is:"
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("CurrentTimeTimeString").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "-- WAIT -- --"
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 75, 141)
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("SubTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 60
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Start " & Now
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("SubTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = " ----- " & Now
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("CurrentTimeTimeString").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(191, 191, 191)
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("CurrentTimeTimeString").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(Now, "HH:MM AM/PM")
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 75, 141)

    
     DoEvents


CountTimeEnd = Now()

myHours = 0
myMinutes = 3
mySeconds = 0

CountTimeEnd = DateAdd("h", myHours, CountTimeEnd)
CountTimeEnd = DateAdd("n", myMinutes, CountTimeEnd)
CountTimeEnd = DateAdd("s", mySeconds, CountTimeEnd)

ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 138

countTimeStart = Now()
    sTalk.Speak "The Time is Now " & Format(Now, "HH:MM AM/PM"), SVSFDefault
    sTalk.Speak "The session will end at " & Format(CountTimeEnd, "HH:MM AM/PM"), SVSFDefault
    sTalk.Speak "Your Time Starts Now. Good Luck.", SVSFlagsAsync
    
Do Until CountTimeEnd < Now()

    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("CurrentTimeHeading").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "The Current Time Is:"
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("CurrentTimeTimeString").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(Now, "HH:MM.SS AM/PM")

    secondsRemain = (DateDiff("s", Now, CountTimeEnd))
    timePassed = DateDiff("s", countTimeStart, Now)
    
    dispH = Int(secondsRemain / (60 * 60))
    dispM = Int(secondsRemain / 60) Mod 60
    dispS = secondsRemain Mod 60
    
    timePassedH = Int(timePassed / (60 * 60))
    timePassedM = Int(timePassed / 60) Mod 60
    timePassedS = secondsRemain Mod 60
    
    If dispH > 0 Then
        ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 75, 141)
        dispTime = Format(dispH, "00") & ":" & Format(dispM, "00") & "." & Format(dispS, "00")
    ElseIf dispM > 0 Then
        If dispM >= 10 Then
            ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 75, 141)
        ElseIf dispM >= 5 Then
            ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(227, 108, 9)
        Else
            ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(243, 60, 4)
        End If
        dispTime = Format(dispM, "00") & ":" & Format(dispS, "00")
    Else
        If dispS Mod 2 = 0 Then
            ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(218, 31, 5)
            ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("SubTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(253, 228, 42)
        Else
            ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(161, 1, 0)
            ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("SubTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 202, 42)
        End If
        dispTime = Format(dispS, "00")
    End If
    
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = dispTime
    
    If dispH > 0 Or dispM > 0 Then
        ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("SubTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Time Remaining"
    Else
        ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("SubTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Time Remaining (Seconds)" & vbNewLine & _
            "Please ensure all answers are on your answer document." & vbNewLine & "No additional time will be provided to transfer your answers."
    End If
    
    DoEvents
    
Debug.Print DateDiff("n", Now, countTimeStart)
    
    If dispH = 1 And dispM = 30 And dispS = 0 Then
        If bGave_90M_Warning = False Then
            If timePassedH > 1 And timePassedM > 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hours and " & timePassedM & "minutes have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH > 1 And timePassedM = 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hours have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 1 And timePassedM > 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hour and " & timePassedM & "minutes have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 1 And timePassedM = 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hour has elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 0 And timePassedM = 1 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedM & " minute has elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 0 And timePassedM > 1 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedM & " minutes have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            Else
                'say nothing
            End If
            
            sTalk.Speak "You have one hour and thirty minutes remaining.", SVSFlagsAsync
        End If
        bGave_90M_Warning = True
    End If
    
    If dispH = 1 And dispM = 0 And dispS = 0 Then
        If bGave_60M_Warning = False Then
            If timePassedH > 1 And timePassedM > 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hours and " & timePassedM & "minutes have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH > 1 And timePassedM = 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hours have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 1 And timePassedM > 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hour and " & timePassedM & "minutes have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 1 And timePassedM = 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hour has elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 0 And timePassedM = 1 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedM & " minute has elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 0 And timePassedM > 1 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedM & " minutes have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            Else
                'say nothing
            End If
            
            sTalk.Speak "You have one hour remaining.", SVSFlagsAsync
        End If
        bGave_60M_Warning = True
    End If
    
    If dispH = 0 And dispM = 30 And dispS = 0 Then
        If bGave_30M_Warning = False Then
            If timePassedH > 1 And timePassedM > 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hours and " & timePassedM & "minutes have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH > 1 And timePassedM = 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hours have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 1 And timePassedM > 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hour and " & timePassedM & "minutes have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 1 And timePassedM = 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hour has elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 0 And timePassedM = 1 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedM & " minute has elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 0 And timePassedM > 1 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedM & " minutes have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            Else
                'say nothing
            End If
        
            sTalk.Speak "You have thirty minutes remaining.", SVSFlagsAsync
        End If
        bGave_30M_Warning = True
    End If
    
    If dispH = 0 And dispM = 15 And dispS = 0 Then
        If bGave_15M_Warning = False Then
                    If timePassedH > 1 And timePassedM > 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hours and " & timePassedM & "minutes have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH > 1 And timePassedM = 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hours have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 1 And timePassedM > 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hour and " & timePassedM & "minutes have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 1 And timePassedM = 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hour has elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 0 And timePassedM = 1 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedM & " minute has elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 0 And timePassedM > 1 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedM & " minutes have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            Else
                'say nothing
            End If

            sTalk.Speak "You now have fifteen minutes remaining.", SVSFlagsAsync
        End If
        bGave_15M_Warning = True
    End If
    
    If dispH = 0 And dispM = 10 And dispS = 0 Then
        If bGave_10M_Warning = False Then
            If timePassedH > 1 And timePassedM > 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hours and " & timePassedM & "minutes have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH > 1 And timePassedM = 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hours have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 1 And timePassedM > 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hour and " & timePassedM & "minutes have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 1 And timePassedM = 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hour has elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 0 And timePassedM = 1 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedM & " minute has elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 0 And timePassedM > 1 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedM & " minutes have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            Else
                'say nothing
            End If
            
            sTalk.Speak "You now have ten minutes remaining.", SVSFlagsAsync
        End If
        bGave_10M_Warning = True
    End If
    
    If dispH = 0 And dispM = 5 And dispS = 0 Then
        If bGave_05M_Warning = False Then
            If timePassedH > 1 And timePassedM > 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hours and " & timePassedM & "minutes have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH > 1 And timePassedM = 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hours have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 1 And timePassedM > 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hour and " & timePassedM & "minutes have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 1 And timePassedM = 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hour has elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 0 And timePassedM = 1 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedM & " minute has elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 0 And timePassedM > 1 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedM & " minutes have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            Else
                'say nothing
            End If

            sTalk.Speak "You now have only five minutes remaining. Please ensure all answers are on your answer document.", SVSFlagsAsync
        End If
        bGave_05M_Warning = True
    End If
    
    If dispH = 0 And dispM = 1 And dispS = 0 Then
         If bGave_01M_Warning = False Then
            If timePassedH > 1 And timePassedM > 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hours and " & timePassedM & "minutes have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH > 1 And timePassedM = 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hours have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 1 And timePassedM > 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hour and " & timePassedM & "minutes have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 1 And timePassedM = 0 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedH & " hour has elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 0 And timePassedM = 1 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedM & " minute has elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            ElseIf timePassedH = 0 And timePassedM > 1 Then
                sTalk.Speak timePassedM & " minutes have elapsed", SVSFlagsAsync
            Else
                'say nothing
            End If
            
            sTalk.Speak "You now have one minute remaining. Please ensure all answers are on your answer document.", SVSFlagsAsync
        
        End If
        bGave_01M_Warning = True
    End If
        
    DoEvents
Loop
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("CurrentTimeTimeString").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(Now, "HH:MM AM/PM")
DoEvents

    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("Rect_CO_HEADER").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(222, 245, 250)
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("Rect_CO_Header").Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(192, 0, 0)
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("Rect_CO_Info").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(242, 242, 255)
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("Rect_CO_Header").Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(228, 0, 70)

    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 138
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Stop Working"
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 22, 60)
DoEvents
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("SubTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Please put your pens and pencils down. Please return all examination materials, including scrap paper and reference sheets, to the examination envelope. Please bring the envelope up to the proctors. Thank you."
    DoEvents
    
    sTalk.Speak "Your Time is up", SVSFDefault
    
    DoEvents
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 72
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Pencils/Pens Down"
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 22, 60)
    DoEvents
    sTalk.Speak "Please put your pens and pencils down. "
    
    DoEvents
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 72
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Return Exam"
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 22, 60)
    DoEvents
    sTalk.Speak "Please return all examination materials, including scrap paper and reference sheets, to the examination envelope. "
    DoEvents
    
    sTalk.Speak "Please bring the envelope up to the proctors.", SVSFlagsAsync
    
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 138
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Stop Working"
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 22, 60)
    
    DoEvents
    
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("SubTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Please return all examination materials, including scrap paper and reference sheets, to the examination envelope. Please bring the envelope up to the proctors. Thank you."
   
   DoEvents
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 138
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Thank You."
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 22, 60)
    DoEvents
   
   sTalk.Speak "Thank you for taking your examination with us. "
   DoEvents
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 72
   ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Get Home Safely."
   ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 22, 60)
   DoEvents
   
   Select Case Time()
    Case #12:00:01 AM# To #11:59:00 AM#
       sTalk.Speak "Have a good day and get home safely."
    Case #12:00:00 PM# To #4:59:00 PM#
       sTalk.Speak "Have a good afternoon and get home safely."
    Case #4:59:01 PM# To #8:00:00 PM#
       sTalk.Speak "Have a good evening and get home safely."
    Case Else
       sTalk.Speak "Have a good night and get home safely."
    End Select
    DoEvents
    
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Time Is Up"
   DoEvents
    BAR01_ContinueCurrentTime 600 'Continue Live Clock for 10 minutes

End Sub

Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()
        Debug.Print SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.SlideIndex
        If SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.SlideIndex = TimerSlideNumber Then
            BAR01_Countdown
       End If
End Sub

Private Sub BAR01_ContinueCurrentTime(lLengthInSeconds As Long)
Dim bDis As Boolean
    bDis = True

Dim CT_CountTimeEnd As Date

    CT_CountTimeEnd = Now()
    CT_CountTimeEnd = DateAdd("s", CInt(lLengthInSeconds), CT_CountTimeEnd)


Do Until CT_CountTimeEnd < Now()

    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("CurrentTimeHeading").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "The Current Time Is:"
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("CurrentTimeTimeString").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(Now, "HH:MM.SS AM/PM")
    
    
    
    If (Second(Now) >= 0 And Second(Now) < 4) Or (Second(Now) >= 10 And Second(Now) < 14) _
        Or (Second(Now) >= 20 And Second(Now) < 24) Or (Second(Now) >= 30 And Second(Now) < 34) Or _
        (Second(Now) >= 40 And Second(Now) < 44) Or (Second(Now) >= 50 And Second(Now) < 54) Then
            ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 138
            ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Time Is Up"
            ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ElseIf (Second(Now) >= 4 And Second(Now) < 7) Or (Second(Now) >= 14 And Second(Now) < 17) _
        Or (Second(Now) >= 24 And Second(Now) < 27) Or (Second(Now) >= 34 And Second(Now) < 37) Or _
        (Second(Now) >= 44 And Second(Now) < 47) Or (Second(Now) >= 54 And Second(Now) < 57) Then
            ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 72
            ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Return Packet To Front"
            ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(227, 108, 9)
            ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Else
        ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 138
        ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Stop Working"
        ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(161, 1, 0)
        ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If

    DoEvents
Loop
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("CurrentTimeHeading").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "The Current Time Is:"
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("CurrentTimeTimeString").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("CurrentTimeTimeString").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "- FINISHED -"
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ActivePresentation.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 75, 141)
        
    DoEvents
End Sub

Private Sub App_PresentationOpen(ByVal Pres As Presentation)

    Pres.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 138
    Pres.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Don't Start. "
    Pres.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("SubTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Please Wait. " & Now
    Pres.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("CurrentTimeHeading").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "The Current Time Is:"
    Pres.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("CurrentTimeTimeString").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "-- WAIT -- --"
    Pres.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 75, 141)
    Pres.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("SubTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Pres.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("CurrentTimeTimeString").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(191, 191, 191)
    Pres.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("CurrentTimeTimeString").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(Now, "HH:MM.SS AM/PM")
    Pres.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Pres.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 75, 141)

End Sub


Private Sub App_SlideShowEnd(ByVal Pres As Presentation)
    Pres.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 138
    Pres.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("CurrentTimeHeading").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "The Current Time Is:"
    Pres.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("CurrentTimeTimeString").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(191, 191, 191)
    Pres.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("CurrentTimeTimeString").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "-- -WAIT- -- "
    Pres.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 75, 141)
    Pres.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("MainTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Please Wait. The time is: " & Now
    Pres.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("SubTitle").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Please Wait. " & Now
    Pres.Slides(TimerSlideNumber).Shapes("CurrentTimeTimeString").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(191, 191, 191)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to produce a much simpler but reproducible example. It's a lot to expect of people that they plow through pages of your code when you don't even indicate a line or two where something's not working the way you expect it to.
That said, you may've just run into one of PPT's quirks. After making changes to on-screen content, try using

```
ActiveWindow.View.GoToSlide(x)
```

where x is the index of the slide you've changed. If that doesn't work, try adding a shape off slide, then deleting it before the GoToSlide code.
That will sometimes force a refresh.